# Message Composer in Mac Catalyst not working

Tags: macos, mac-catalyst, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I have an iOS app that gives support to Mac Catalyst (and runs in Mac OS). In the app, I have a feature where users can send text messages (basically select phone number, enter message content) via MFMessageComposeViewController.
And the code for which is:

```
if MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() {
    let composeVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()
    composeVC.messageComposeDelegate = self
    composeVC.recipients = recipients
    composeVC.body = body
    self.present(composeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This piece of code works fine in iOS as well as in Mac OS (till mac os bigSur i.e, 11.6, and I tested this by myself). But in the latest Mac OS i.e., Mac OS Monterey (12.0+) this is not working. Basically the method `MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText()` always returns `false`.
And if I run the code without checking this condition (just for testing purposes) I get the below exception:

```
[MFMessageComposeViewController] Unable to initialize due to + [MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText] returns NO.
An uncaught exception was raised
Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target <MyApp.ViewControllerName:0x7fe3d6e67120>
```

Has anyone faced this issue or does anyone know if this is an OS bug or something's updated in the code in the latest OS?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I am having the same issue.  I've just submitted a bug report Apple via Xcode Feedback, so I'll see if I can any response.  I suggest you do the same.

Comment: Did anyone find a solution for the above?

Comment: This is weird. It fails for me as well under macOS 13.4. But oddly, if I present a UIActivityViewController, Messages is an option and I can send a text through the OS provided interface.